# Weird border while playing fullscreen

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, fallout-3

I have the following problem while playing some (Bethesda) games, if i set the game to fullscreen (non-windowed).

In the upper right corner of the screen, it looks like there is the regular " windows-window" border quickly blinking. Its's always the upper right corner  (the three buttons your normally see in a window plus some extra empty space) and it annoys me to no end. It looks as if the game is trying to switch between fullscreen and windowed mode. I have only encountered the problem with bethesda games so far. I find it very hard to explain what exactly happens, but I hope some of you have encountered the same and know a solution

---

The card I am using is a Sapphire hd 7850

As far as I know, I am running the latest drivers for this card.

I do have some Rainmeter widgets on my desktop

Comment: press alt + enter keys may fix it.

Comment: can you be more specific? what is your video card? are your drivers updated? Skyrim is known to glitch in some drivers. Also do you have some gadget on screen that tells you your CPU,RAM,GPU,etc usage?

Comment: I got that too with Skyrim and other Bethesda Games, I know what you mean. But I don't think that is fixable. One could try to set a different windows style for the game window by sending some WinAPI messages, but that would require further examination and I don't have Skyrim installed atm.

Comment: you could also try alt - tab out and back in to your game. This fixed the problem a few times for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea...this happens when you possibly play the game on the lowest resolution it can be easily solved be pressing alt + tab, or windows key + tab, then it take you off the game screen to your home destop.Once there click on the skyrim icon to go to the game again,of this doesn't work alt+enter will surely solve it.

Comment: Well, I play on 1920x1080..

Comment: What's your full resolution

Comment: i believe i have a 1920x1080 monitor, or i might be misunderstanding the question

Comment: Ok....when you launch skyrim,with the laucher, what resolution do you pick,to start the game

Comment: i pick 1920x1080

Comment: Try to increase a little but of everything on the launcher

Comment: If you pc can handle it

Comment: Im already running everything on the highest setting possible

Comment: has this been going on since you bought the game or after recent updates

Comment: Ever since i have bought the game ( skyrim AND fallout )

Comment: but it doesn't affect your game play?

Comment: Well it is mighty annoying. It doesnt make it impossible for me to play, but it significantly diminishes my will to even start the game. I might even get a seizure due to the flickering corner  :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8966/discussion-between-ian-escobar-and-gutanoth)